# Add and remove instance of an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a small problem

I have to do this with activity A.

A(1st instance)------>A(2nd instance)----------->A(3rd instance)

When moving from 2nd instance of A to the 3rd instance of A, I would like to remove 2nd instance from backstack..

Now there should be only 1st and 3rd instance of A in backstack.

How can I achieve this function?

Could someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you call finish() on 2nd instance activity when starting 3rd instance?

Comment: In this step: A(2nd instance)----------->A(3rd instance), you call 
startActivity and finish()

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call finish() after you call startActivity() from your Activity(2nd instance)